# set a Git config recursively for all submodules

Tags: git, git-config

I need to run the command:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

The problem is that I have a few projects with at least ten submodules each. For some reason, all the submodules have that value set to true so I would have to remove/update that config manually.

Is there a way to tell Git to set a config value to all submodules?

Or remove it from the submodules so that the containing repo's settings are not overwritten?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `git submodule foreach` command for this: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.6.1.3/git-submodule.html

You can provide an arbitrary shell command as a parameter, in your case something like this:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git config core.filemode false
```

This will execute `git config core.filemode false` in each of the submodules of the current Git repo.

Comment: This can be applied to a lot of things, perfect, thank's!

Comment: This doesn't apply to submodules in depth ≥ 2 (submodules of submodules..) therefore `--recursive` must be added → `git submodule foreach --recursive git config core.filemode false`.

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer.